# Nested For Loop Array Searching

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, nested-loops

searchCritera[] has a list of Strings
folderFiles[] has a list of Strings
using searchCriteria[] i'm trying to find from the elements within it if the elements in folderFiles[] have any matches using folderFiles[i].contains(searchCriteria[i].getName()) which resides in an if statement within the nested for loop.
Constant nullpointer throws though.
folderFiles is a list of files within a folder.

```
for(int i = 0; i < searchCriteria.length; i++)
{
    for(int x = 0; x < folderFiles.length; x++)
    {
        if(folderFiles[x].contains(searchCriteria[i]))
        {
            //...
        }
    }
}
```

so glad that was figured out, another problem though.

```
for(int i = 0; i < dirs.length; i++)
        {
            if(dirs[i] != "")
            {
                dirs2[count2] = dirs[i];
                count2++;
            }
        }
        File folder;
        File[] folderFiles;
        for(int i = 0; i < dirs2.length;i++)
        {
            folder = new File(dirs2[i]);
            folderFiles = folder.listFiles();
            for(int x = 0; x < folderFiles.length; x++)
            {
                System.out.println(folderFiles[x].getName());
            }
        }
```

### It'll print a good majority of the files in each directory to console but throws java.lang.NullPointerException

100% it's the second for loop inside of the first there that's causing it not me trying to print to console just commented it out to test.

The first for loop i < dirs2.length seems to be overiding the second inner loops directory as it's trying to process the info it has so i'm pretty sure that's what is causing the issue. no clue how to slow the first loop to wait on second inner loop to finish what it's doing but that seems like the solution

Comment: NullPointerExceptions will tell you on what line it is happening. Can you post some log here?

Comment: Yes, we need a stack trace. Also what are dirs2 and count2?

Comment: count2 = 0; dirs2 is just a passed filtered out array with no null elements, count2 a second int that's used to count up for each match found but unused really, the nullpointer is on the for(int x = 0; x < folderFiles.length; x++) line

Comment: The first if statement up top is to filter out the non null entries from the first array of directories dirs, into a newly created one dirs2 of size of how many elements are not null

Answer (score 0):

I think you have swapped x and i.